# Error al leer Entry en tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, entrada

Buen dia. Estoy realizando una simple entrada de dato mediante un entry en la libreria tkinter de python pero al momento de obtener lo que el usuario escribio mediante el metodo .get() siempre me marca 0 y no me detecta los cambios en la caja.

```
def interfaz_formulageneral():
   ventana1= tkinter.Tk() #Declaramos una ventana
   ventana1.title("Formula general")
   ventana1.geometry('380x380') 
   ventana1.configure(background='dark turquoise') 

   label_a=tkinter.Label(ventana1, text="Ingresa A", bg="dark turquoise") 
   label_a.pack(padx=5,pady=4,ipadx=5,ipady=5, fill=tkinter.X)
   entrada_a=tkinter.Entry(ventana1, textvariable = dato_a) 
   entrada_a.pack(fill=tkinter.X,padx=5,pady=5, ipadx=5,ipady=5) 

   boton_aceptar=tkinter.Button(ventana1, text="ACEPTAR", command= 
   calculo_formulageneral) 
   boton_aceptar.pack()
   ventana.mainloop() 


def calculo_formulageneral():
    num=dato_a.get()
    print(num)
    return resultado.set(num)


resultado= tkinter.StringVar()
dato_a= tkinter.DoubleVar()

interfaz_formulageneral()
```

En esta parte del codigo solo estoy haciendo una prueba. Al momento de presionar aceptar quiero que se imprima en consola el valor del entry pero por mas que presione aceptar y modifique el cuadro de entrada siempre se imprime 0.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con el siguiente codigo:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()

def interfaz_formulageneral():

   label_a = Label(ventana, text ="Ingresa A", bg ="dark turquoise") 
   label_a.grid(row = 0, column= 0, padx = 5, pady = 4, sticky = W + E)

   entrada_a = Entry(ventana, textvariable = dato_a) 
   entrada_a.grid(row = 0, column = 1, padx = 5, pady = 5, ipadx = 5, ipady = 5, sticky= W + E )
   entrada_a.config(justify = "right") 

   boton_aceptar = Button(ventana, text = "ACEPTAR", command = calculo_formulageneral) 
   boton_aceptar.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
   boton_aceptar.config(justify = "center")

def calculo_formulageneral():
    num = dato_a.get()
    print(num)


dato_a = StringVar()
interfaz_formulageneral()

ventana.title("Formula general")
ventana.geometry('380x380') 
ventana.config(bg='dark turquoise') 

ventana.mainloop()
```

Comment: Bienvenido Ermin... Puedes detallar el funcionamiento del código? Explicar hace que el OP entienda por qué tu respuesta sería la correcta, y también ayudará si alguien tiene el mismo problema en el futuro..  Ve a [answer] para más información

Answer (score 0):

Te he puesto el código de manera sencilla con un botón que hace que se ejecute la función `clicAceptar`:

```
from tkinter import *

def clicAceptar():
    print(user.get())

def interfaz_formulageneral():
    # crea la caja de texto que recogera la variable user
    usuario = Entry(root, textvariable=user)
    usuario.grid()

    # crea el boton, al clicar ejecutará la función clicAceptar
    boton = Button(root, text="Aceptar", command=clicAceptar)
    boton.grid()

root = Tk()

# creamos la variable que contendrá el nombre del usuario
user = StringVar()

interfaz_formulageneral()
root.mainloop()
```

Con el código anterior puedes imprimir en consola lo que has escrito en entry.

Pasando a tu código, te está fallando porque tienes que sacar `ventana1 = tkinter.Tk()` y

`ventana1.mainloop()` de la función, quedando tu código así:.

```
def interfaz_formulageneral():

    ventana1.title("Formula general")
    ventana1.geometry('380x380')
    ventana1.configure(background='dark turquoise')

    label_a = tkinter.Label(ventana1, text="Ingresa A", bg="dark turquoise")
    label_a.pack(padx=5, pady=4, ipadx=5, ipady=5, fill=tkinter.X)
    entrada_a = tkinter.Entry(ventana1, textvariable=dato_a)
    entrada_a.pack(fill=tkinter.X, padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

    boton_aceptar = tkinter.Button(
        ventana1, text="ACEPTAR", command=calculo_formulageneral)
    boton_aceptar.pack()


def calculo_formulageneral():
    num = dato_a.get()
    print(num)
    return resultado.set(num)


ventana1 = tkinter.Tk()

resultado = tkinter.StringVar()
dato_a = tkinter.DoubleVar()

interfaz_formulageneral()

ventana1.mainloop()
```